# Reading a directory for files then displaying them on a pygame surface

Tags: python-3.x, file, variables, pygame

I have a function that reads a directory called "Games" and looks through it for certain files. This part works fine. The problem is that I want to calculate how many files there are and for each file I want to add 10 to a variable.

```
def games():
    f = 0
    sy = 100
    ftext = pygame.font.SysFont("Arial", 20)
    while True:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                pygame.quit()
                quit()
        screen.fill(DarkSpace)
        ToolBarButton("Home", 0, 0, 150, 50, SpaceGrey, CornflowerBlue, 10, cmain)
        ToolBarButton(username, 153,0,150,50, SpaceGrey, CornflowerBlue, 10, accountDetails)
        ToolBarButton("Programs", 305,0,150,50, SpaceGrey, CornflowerBlue, 10, programs)
        ToolBarButton("Games", 458,0,150,50, SpaceGrey, CornflowerBlue, 10, games)
        ToolBarButton("Help", 610,0,150,50, SpaceGrey, CornflowerBlue, 10, hel)
        DropDown(NeonGreen, CornflowerBlue, 764, 16, 30, 30, DropMenu)
        Btext(screen, "Loading Games!", CornflowerBlue, ftext, 600,600,600,600)
        fileDir = os.listdir(r"D:\Users\26099\Desktop\Programming\Dark_Dragons\Blunt_Wars1\venv\Launcher\Games")
        nf = len(fileDir)
        while nf > f:
            f += 1
            sy += 10
            break
        print(sy)
        for fileN in fileDir:
            verif = fileN.endswith('.py') or fileN.endswith('.pyw')
            if not verif:
                fileDir.remove(fileN)
            else:
                print(fileN)
                text(screen, fileN, CornflowerBlue, ftext, 300,sy)
        pygame.display.update()
```

So i want to add 100 to sy for every file with a certain extension. I tried putting it into a for loop but ti got an error saying int object is not callable so does anyone know how to go about this

Answer (score 0):

To get the number of files in the directory, you can do this (that's called a 'list comprehension' and is similar to a `for` loop that appends the files to an empty list):

```
files = [f for f in os.listdir() if os.path.isfile(f)]
num_files = len(files)
```

If you want to count specific extensions, you could do something like this (better use a dictionary instead of separate variables):

```
py_files = 0
pyw_files = 0
for file_name in os.listdir():
    if file_name.endswith('.py'):
        py_files += 1
    elif file_name.endswith('.pyw'):
        pyw_files += 1
```

Or in a more sophisticated way with a `collections.Counter`:

```
import collections

extensions = collections.Counter(
    os.path.splitext(f)[1] for f in os.listdir() if os.path.isfile(f))
print(extensions, sum(extensions.values()))
```

Additional notes:

Don't modify lists while you're iterating over them. That leads to unexpected results. Create a new, filtered list instead.

The `while nf > f:` loop looks pointless. You could just multiply `nf` by `10`: `sy = nf * 10`. Also, because you call `break`, you end the loop after the first iteration.

You probably don't have to recount the files every frame, hundreds of times per second, so I'd do that once ahead of the `while` loop or when an event occurs.

Comment: This is bit helpful but it doesn't answer my question. I want to know hot to find all files with that extension and then print that to the console. This doesn't really work for me as it shows files that aren't even in my folder.

Comment: You have to pass the correct path to [`os.listdir`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.listdir) if the script is not in the same directory. Do you want to get the actual files or just the number of files? If you want the number you can use the `collections.Counter` solution and write for example `print(extensions['.py'])` to print the number of .py files.

Answer (score 0):

use os.walk.

```
x = [_ for _ in os.walk("../source")][0]

# index-10-> file path
# index-1 -> folders in directory
# index-2 -> files in directory
```